# Problem with migration when i am implementing paper clip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

[image]

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
    def change
    create_table :lists do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The error is as follows and I cannot figure out how to fix it - any more experienced people know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: class AddAttachmentAvatarToLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
    def change
    create_table :lists do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: Don't use rails 3/4 tags that have nothing to do with your current rails version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paperclip doesn't seem to work on Rails 7. There's a fork that might work for you - see reported issue at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2698